# Flutter webview cannot upload file from input field

Tags: flutter, file-upload, webview

I've tried using [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview/) or [flutter_webview_pro](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_pro/), I'm able to select a file or take a screenshot, but unfortunately, after I try to select the file, it displays a wrong message in the input field, and the file is not uploaded.

`C:\fakepath\FILENAME_com.android.captiveportallogin`

The webview is loading, other inputs are working, no error in the console.

I'm using *Flutter SDK 2.10.0* and latest versions for webview plugins.

Does someone else encounter a similar issue?

Comment: Did you try using webview_flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and enabling hybrid composition to true? It solves multiple keyboard and input issues.

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. I will try and the post update if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This was a long standing issue in Flutter, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27924 especially on Android. However, with `webview_flutter 4.0.2` this functionality has been fixed and now works perfectly.

In the `initState`, you just need to call the following code

```
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      final androidController = controller.platform as AndroidWebViewController;
      await androidController.setOnShowFileSelector(_androidFilePicker);
    }
```

Now, on every file upload button press on WebView, `_androidFilePicker` function will be called. In this function, you can use any [file picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker) to select and upload files. There is an excellent blog post with code snippets on [file upload with Flutter](https://theprogrammingway.com/flutter-file-upload-using-webview-on-android/), if you need to go in details.