# File upload not working in webview_flutter for android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, file-upload, webview

I have a Vue.js Web application which uses a file uploader. But this is not working in android webview but it is working fine in iOS. Can anyone help on this.

A solution to make the file uploader works on webview_flutter so that i can upload files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/77155112/1979347 for fixing file upload issue on Android using webview.